# How to limit population growth in a utopia?

Tags: internal-consistency, biology, society, humans, medical

In my fictional nation, the government has figured out how to provide sufficient nutrition to the entire population indiscriminately. This leaves most citizens time to explore and develop technologies and artisanal crafts. This is similar to what has happened in real life. However, due to the increased life expectancy, there has been an enormous jump in human populations.

This image uses data from the UN Population Division:[image]

If I am looking to avoid this scenario, how can I achieve this using hard science?

**Background:**
My fictional nation lives in a mixed temperate grasslands and forests biome on a planet with average wind speeds of 20 mph where they live. Basic food and water are provided for every citizen, but harder-working citizens earn better supplies. Disease is unfeasible since these humans have an immune system similar to bats. I want to create a civilization that has a limited population at all times. This can be in the form of long-living humans or a high death rate. Systemic purging and relocation are not feasible options. I'm looking for biological changes, like something about fertility or decreasing life expectancy. This is not a governmental issue, I purely want to prevent ecological and societal damage from humans over the years on this planet. A stable population is preferable, just at low numbers.

**Question:**
So, what can be done to avoid a growing population in this fictional utopia?

*I am completely new to Stack Exchange, so please let me know what I can improve*

Comment: Welcome to worldbuilding. One thing you can fix is the difference between what you are asking in the title and in the body of the question. Population growth and population ageing are two different things.

Comment: How are you defining "elderly?" Hint: And how is that definition different from, say, 100 or 200 years ago? For example, George Washington took command of the Continental Army at age 44, and died at age 67. During his lifetime, average life expectancy ranged from 30-40, so 67 seems mighty elderly...by the standards of that time. But not today.

Comment: Frame challenge, why do you want to? what downside of an aging population do you not want.

Comment: Do you want to restrict population growth, or population aging? You need to choose one.

Comment: @user535733  That's a myth, if I recall correctly.  Average life expectancy was low before the twentieth century because of high childhood mortality rates.  Anyone who survived to adulthood in pre-modern times could expect a life expectancy not much different that what we see today.

Comment: Title change aside.
I'm not sure about: A) can be done in any way that does not evolve extreme measures such as murdering older people.
B)Why?
I'm not for asking you to justify what you what because it is your world after all. Ask how to destroy the universe if you want. But in this example I'm having a hard time putting it together.
Utopia but the government does not like people growing old. Does not match up.
So please provide more context as to why they want that or what is going on.
Like are people getting too old so they require more care from the state...etc

Comment: The title asks about restricting population growth, the body of the question asks about restricting the number of old people. Those two questions are not the same *at all*. The only way to keep the average age low is to kill old people, by disease or otherwise; this comes in contraction with the affirmation that *"life expectancy increases"*. You cannot have at the same time a long life expectancy at birth, *and* a low average age, *and* a stable population. Voting to close as unclear what you are asking.

Comment: @GrumpyYoungMan: Not much different from that we see today... except that it was some 10 to 15 years lower. (That's why the proverbial nominal lifespan is [three score and ten](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Psalm%2090%3A10&version=KJV). Nowadays most developed countries have life expectancies at birth of more that 80 years, and people who make it past childhood fully expect to reach 85.)

Comment: "There is more crime, supply chain issues" - this is definitely untrue, if taking developed countries as an example. This was true throughout the history as the growing cities were outstripping society's capability of managing them - but here is the Utopia, right?

Comment: How is this different from the real world? In most developed countries, and in quite a few developing countries, food and health care are provided for every citizen. In most places famines are thing of the past. And yet somehow the population of those countries is not growing. (And the current predictions of the relevant oracles are that the population of the world will stop growing before the end of the century.)

Comment: @AlexP  "Three score and ten" (70, for those unfamiliar with the archaism) is significantly higher than the "30-40" from the original comment so you're basically saying the same thing I did.

Comment: @GrumpyYoungMan quibbling with the example is fun, but seems to miss the point of the comment: That the OP hasn't defined "elderly". Can older folks continue to be window installers and doctors and telephone sanitizers and computer programmers in that society? Are the elderly a burden or a benefit in that society? The implication is 'burden'...which is also a myth.

Comment: One point: every utopian novel I've ever read is really a dystopian novel in hiding. Maybe this isn't universally true, but it is in my experience. Having the government deal with the problem in a nasty way would be what I'd expect.

Comment: It sounds harsh but the only solution is sterilization of the people after their first or second child.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

### It will happen automatically, in fact it has already happened in your society. You are worried about nothing.

If you have a civilization with the following features: low mortality, high standard of living, abundant resources, the population stops growing. Evolution actually favors K strategy in these situations, that having few offspring but investing a lot of resources in to them. This is why the populations of most first world countries are stable once you account for immigration. K strategy is having few children and investing a lot of time and effort in those children. r strategy is having many offspring but having to devote less time and energy to each becasue you divide it among a larger number. r strategy works best if child mortality is high, K strategy is much more successful if child mortality is low because the children of K strategist are on average much more desirable mates.

Populations grow primarily during the *transition* from high mortality to low mortality, which is happening and has happened all over the earth right now. Many countries are transitioning to high standards of living ([Here is a great talk about this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=usdJgEwMinM)). the population grows when people are still having children as if most of them will die when most will survive. If your civilization actually has the features you describe its population will be already be stable, just like in real world countries it happened within the first generation or two of mortality reaching the point described.

Comment: More about the transition: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demographic_transition

Comment: Automatically? Only in the short term (a few generations). in the long term, your population will come to be dominated by the (initially rare) weirdos who LOVE, absolutely LOVE to have many children.

Comment: @SerbanTanasa No having fewer children is actually evolutionarily favored under these circumstances, having few high investment children yields more decedents becasue they are more successful at finding mates in the highly contentions mate competition created.  I suggest you look up K and r strategy. Your people might have more children but the have fewer grandchildren.

Comment: Yes, it will happen automatically, eventually.  That doesn't mean you have nothing to worry about.  Until evolution finds equilibrium, you may face overpopulation, mass death, and a population crash.  So if you're perfectly fine with those, then sure I guess you have nothing to worry about.

Comment: Also, K strategy is based on evolution, but humans are animals which are not subject to just natural selection:  we are quite adept at artificially selecting ourselves.

Comment: @cowlinator That would only happen before the utopia comes into existence. under hte given conditions infant mortality is already taken care of, the only change is in food supply, which is a far weaker influence. Also we are not talking about extrapolation we have actually seen the transition happen in humans many times. Unless they engage in large scale genetic engineering or some pretty extreme social engineering this will happen.

Comment: From the Wikipedia article in the comment: "Some dissenting scholars note that the modern environment is exerting evolutionary pressure for higher fertility, and that eventually due to individual natural selection or due to cultural selection, birthrates may rise again. Part of the "cultural selection" hypothesis is that the variance in birthrate between cultures is significant; for example, some religious cultures have a higher birthrate that isn't accounted for by differences in income."

Comment: And critically: "It [the Demographic Transition Model] is not applicable for high levels of development, as it has been shown that after a HDI [Human Development Index] of 0.9 the fertility increases again."

Comment: @DanielR.Collins have you actually read any of those dissents they are all marginal, and several have been criticized for using HDI which weighs income as equal to infant mortality when we know infant mortality has a much bigger effect. You can be rich and still have high infant mortality, like the US or Qatar. HDI is a NOT a good way to predict this. the numbers reverse becasue the US comes out with a high HDI when it has a infant mortality rate worse then Bosnia and numerically dominates the >9 HDI population. Its bad statistics.

Comment: @John: As usual, I'll trust published scholarly articles (e.g., Myrskylä et. al. in *Nature* 2009) over "random guy on internet", unless you can provide quality citation.

Comment: @DanielR.Collins here a refutation of income as a corollary,  https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/00324728.2020.1810746 and a follow up study showing the faults in Myrskyla's study, and that their trend does not stand up to scrutiny.  https://ideas.repec.org/a/ebl/ecbull/eb-09-00739.html and another breakdown of the studies faults here, http://monkeysuncle.stanford.edu/?p=415 just becasue something is published does not make it accurate, you have to look at the follow work as well.

Comment: @John If your society just accepts letting the descendants of those people starve to death.

Comment: Precisely.  Don't use science, use economics.

Comment: Waiting for it to happen naturally would end up abruptly in wars, famine and the destruction of most resources and nature.

It seems much better to prevent that situation by controlling birthrate softly.

And it could be not too hard to control your country's birthrate, but it's almost impossible to control the birthrate of other countries, specially those witch cultures promoting to have as many children as possible. They will reject any interference.

Comment: @skan there is no reason to believe any of that would happen, again we have seen this happen multiple times in the real world, it will happen quickly and automatically without conflict, and there is no top down control involved.

Answer (score 6):

> provide sufficient nutrition

But not sufficient space.  You've solved the famine issue - great.  Now you've got to solve access to health-care, access to living space, and every other problem we struggle with besides getting 3 meals a day.

Japan already don't have enough new births to sustain their population.  Competition for jobs is usually blamed.  Japan already has one of the highest life expectancies in the world and nationalized health-care.
It's an island so space is also at a premium.  People just don't want to start a family.

Comment: I think it's more accurate to say that people don't think they can *afford* to start a family.

Answer (score 6):

Technological solutions (assuming unlimited advanced tech):

## Merging persons

Create a technology that smoothly merges multiple persons into one.

At first compatible (i.e. similarly minded and bodied) people are selected. The more population number is, the more chances that some persons would be almost identical.

The super-technology then connects their minds together: initially they are just subtly starting being alike of each other, then start sharing thoughts, ultimately becoming one hive mind.

After that it wouldn't be much of a problem to merge bodies as well to one big. That big body can than be shrunk, selecting better cells and discarding poorer ones. Just trade 10 aging and sick bodies to 3 healthy and rejuvenated ones.

This may solve most of ethical problems by advanced enough tech - population number is going down, yet nobody gets killed and can procreate as much as wants.

Answer (score 5):

**Make it so that people can't get / don't want children.**

I'm assuming that your society has a fairly high tech level, at least one close to the late 20th century. The more advanced your civilisation, the easier my suggestions become to implement. The things I'm about to suggest go against what we would concider foundational values of our current day culture(s), so one might question if such a society could be seen as utopian. But utopia is a state relative to your values. A right wingers utopia would look far different from a progressives, and both would seem dystopian to the other. With that out of the way, let's go.

As I said, if people don't want children and can't have them, you avoid overpopulation. The first and most important thing is that your civilisation fundamentally believes that normal people having children is an inherently immoral, even evil thing. There are many legitimate reasons for such a belief. Maybe they consider the conservation of nature to be a fundamental duty of their species, and thus controlling their own population is considered to be the right thing. Think "you shall not kill, you shall not steal, you shall not spread uncontrolled". Another option would be that they believe that parents bringing up children is child abuse. After all, in what way is a mother qualified to care for her child? True, nature gave it to her, but nature also gave her arms and legs and when they are broken, she doesn't "know best herself". No, she goes to see a medical professional. Thus, bringing up children is also the job of professionals.

After we took a look at the cultural requirements, its time to consider the biological ones. I don't see any of the beliefs above developing or remaining in place unless people can't have children for biological reasons. The biological software that evolved to make parents care about, "love", their kids is strong and probably hard to remove. Thus, either everyone is just borne sterile, because the species has been genetically modefied or its members are sterilised after birth.

So how do they actually keep their numbers up? There are many options. One might employ artificial womb technology or use sutabile women as wombs. The children are then put in the kind of environment this society considers optimal to bring up children. Maybe there is rigorous testing for suitable couples or groups bring up children in professional patchwork "families" or the children are brought up by some kind of institution.

The point of it all is that these constraints allow them or even force them to make very conscious choices about their population growth. They can plan ahead, project population requirements for their goals, adjust for the losses along the way and get exactly what they want.

Answer (score 4):

You could have a stable society where, say, 90% of the population is retired from work.  That's only a problem if your economy depends on most people having jobs.  But if the proportion of elderly people had been the same for centuries, then of course you *wouldn't* run your economy that way.

Consider that, medically speaking, there is nothing to stop modern humans having five surviving children per adult, which would lead to catastrophic overpopulation within decades.  But we don't need artificial limits or catastrophes to prevent that; if anything, societies with low infant mortality tend to have the opposite problem.

Humans can reason about the future, and humans in industrialised countries can see that having lots of children restricts your (and therefore also your children's) economic and social prospects.  This is reinforced by social changes that accompanied falling child mortality.  Industrial societies banned child labor, made school compulsory, and did other things to ensure that the burden of each new life falls on the individual parents at least as much as on society as a whole.  In fact, by the time women gained more equal rights, it turned out industrial economies had disincentivized having children slightly *too* much (and continue to do so).

So, if you had a really prosperous socialist society where everyone lived to 300, then you might want to mandate that all children be supported in full-time education until age 30.  And a lot more jobs would involve elder care.  But **as long as it happened gradually enough,** there's no obvious reason such a society couldn't be sustainable.

Answer (score 2):

## Enforced birth control: (by government OR by nature)

The answer is right there in your question statement:

> provide sufficient nutrition to the entire population indiscriminately.

and

> but harder-working citizens earn better supplies

Just put contraceptives in the basic food ration, and for those that qualify include either drug-free food or a counteragent for the drugs.

This is easily done via some form of government control. But as the OP has expressed a desire against this approach, it is *still* a viable pathway.

The "free basic food ration" is an easily-grown crop that is available for everyone.
However, this plant has a natural defense against over-grazing. It does NOT become poisonous exactly, but the more it is stressed (by over grazing/harvesting) the more it excretes a hormone that reduces the fertility of the eaters.

As long as the general population is dependent upon this one specific plant for food,  their population density in a given region will adjust to fit the ability of the plant to feed them. Too few, and they are fully fertile and population grows. Too many, and fertility drop, reducing birthrate to below natural death rate thus reducing population.

Comment: I love your reasoning about the plant regulating the population size.

Answer (score 2):

**Cash bonuses for sterilization:**

As a philanthropist, monarch, or governmental agency offer a cash bonus to anyone willing to be sterilized. This has two major advantages over forceful kinds of eugenic acts suggested in other answers:

1. People are doing this voluntarily so nobody can complain about fairness.
2. The people who are doing this are reversing the dysgenic trend portrayed in Idiocracy. So instead of smart healthy people waiting for the “right time” to have a single kid while the rest of the world breeds uncontrollably, those who cannot afford to take care of a child (they need the money) are permanently prevented from doing so.

Answer (score 1):

### Scythes.

Essentially, have a government agency ([or all-powerful NGO](https://www.goodreads.com/series/188984-arc-of-a-scythe)) whose sole job is to kill a certain number of people every year.

Comment: Ha ha, your answer goes soooooo well with your username! Other than that the OP said: "_Systemic purging and relocation are not feasible options_", so I don't think your answer matches his requirements.

Answer (score 1):

**Fecundity inhibitors**

One way to do it biologically would be to make it so that some humans emit a hormone that acts as a fecundity inhibitors when in presence of a lot of other humans.
This ability could have emerged with a darwinian process on subsets of the whole human population. People in a certain continent had an overpopulation which caused famine and lack of resources while others developped more slowly because of this ability. This slow evolution allowed for a more efficient use of resources.
If it doesn't come from a hormone they produced, it could come from some lifestyle habits that reduce fertility like eating a plant which reduces libido or having asocial behaviors in highly crowded places.

Comment: Welcome to [worldbuilding.se]!  We're glad you could join us!  When you have a moment, please [click here](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6388) to learn more about our culture, read the first two bullets of our [help], and take our [tour].  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Free Market Economics.

As presented in Green Mars by Kim Stanley Robinson. Ration that amount of children the population as a whole can have without explicitly enforcing limits on any individual.

> Because you get good narratives, right off the bat. I mean, if the governments of the world would say, "OK, everybody has the legal right to three-quarters of a child, and so you and your partner have the right to a child and a half when you add them up, and so after you’ve had one child you’ve got a half-credit left, and then you either have to buy another half, or you can sell your half," the soap operas that result from this scenario are fantastic!

Comment: Pretty sure that's putting limits on people. What happens when they violate that law by having more children than they have credits for, after all?